# How to run a process in background without typing & every time?

Tags: bash, alias, background-process

For some processes I use, I almost always run them as background processes by indicating that with "&" at the end. Is there a way to make this standard? Would it be possible to use the alias command in the .bashrc file to do this?

Comment: What alias would be as concise as a single character?

Comment: If I use gedit for instance, the command should be "gedit somefile.C &", but I can only use alias to do something like gedit='gedit &', right? How can I tell it to always put the & at the end?

Comment: You can use function instead of the alias. Eg. `function bgedit() { gedit "$@" & }`

Comment: @NarūnasK can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using function instead of the alias. For example to open a file with `gedit` and send it to the background afterwards, add these lines to your `~/.bashrc` (or equivalent if you're not using bash):

```
function bgedit() {
  gedit "$@" &
}
```

Then open some file:

```
bgedit /path/to/somefile
```

If you don't want to change the command name, you can symlink `/usr/local/bin/gedit` to the script which implements similar functionality (a wrapper script).

Comment: Using a function instead of an alias also has the advantage of showing you something aggravatingly obtuse like `[1]- Running gedit "$@" &` when you run `jobs`, instead of `Running gedit /path/to/file &`, which would be too easy.